# Where is link to download Visual Studio Remote debugger tools for VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

Unfortunately, MS block workable link to download VS_RemoteTools_X86 for VS2019 and redirect this link to advertising of Visual Studio 2022. I don't need new Windows, new Visual Studio, new Framework, new Visual Studio for MAC or something other. I need exactly Visual Studio 2019 remote debugger tools, but unfortunately can not found it in MS site. Attempt to install msvsmon.exe to remote machine from local directory with VS2019 was unsuccessful too. And link to repair this issue Microsoft also has been break and also has redirected to meaningless advertising.

[image]

So, is anybody knows where is workable link to Remote debugger tools for VS2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links are definitely there, you're not trying hard enough.

From the [Visual Studio downloads page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) scroll to the bottom where you'll see a link for [Older downloads](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/). Yes, there's another prompt to install VS 2022 but look further down the page is a section for "2019", expand that and you will see download button/link for "Visual Studio 2019 and other Products". The blurb even mentions Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2019 (underlined in red below by me).

[image: VS 2019 download link]

Follow that link (you'll have to sign in) and you'll be taken to a downloads page with a pre-filled search for "Visual Studio 2019". Modify the search "Visual Studio 2019 remote" and it should be easy enough to find.

Comment: unfortunately, this screen can not contain a link. It contain only link to Microsofr Federal authentication for collecting information about users, like phone number and other. And I see page https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads  and searching "Visual Studio 2019 remote debugger tools" or "Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2019 (version  16.9)" send me result - "We didn't find results for "Visual Studio 2019 remote debugger tools"

Comment: oooh, finally I found link !